# Getting a part of IP address String

Tags: java

If I have a IP address String like : `10.120.230.78` I would like to get `10.120.` out of it

But the parts of the address can change from 1 tot 3 numbers as we all know ...

`1.1.1.1` to `255.255.255.255` so ....

I believe you can use a pattern, but I don't have an idea how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ip.substring(0, ip.indexOf('.',ip.indexOf('.') + 1) + 1)
```

where `ip` is the string holding the IP address.

Answer (score 12):

assume you store your ip as a string called ip, you can use `String.split()` to get an array of the parts:

```
String[] tokens = ip.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The best way is `String.split()` as already mentioned by amit.
   E.g.

   ```
   String[] ipAddressParts = ipAddress.split();
   ```
2. Also you can use

   ```
   StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer( ipAddress, "." );
   while ( stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens() )  {
     System.out.println( stringTokenizer.nextToken() );
   }
   ```
3. java.util.Scanner

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at String.split() it's equivalent to php's explode()